# Webpage doesn't render for some Chrome users

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Two of our users report that one of our web pages (http://vdgsa.org/pgs/ads.html) is failing to render properly. Apparently the text of each classified ad is blank, and not taking up space on the screen. For most of our users the page renders correctly.

The common denominator appears to be that the users experiencing problems are using Google Chrome. However, when I look at this page on my computer using the same version of Chrome and the same OS (Windows 7) as one of those users, the page looks fine. Both the HTML and CSS validate. Since I can't duplicate the prob, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happen consistently for these 2 users? and does it fix itself when they scroll the window or resize it or do some action which causes a repaint of the page?

Comment: Scrolling and/or resizing had no effect. Good starting point, though. Fortunately, it turned out to be the AdBlock add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Chrome extension "AdBlock" and don't see the text of the adds.

If I disable adblock and refresh the page, it works normaly (I see the text)

If you download one of the main filter used by AdBlock: [the "Easy List"](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt), you will find many references to the words "ad_titem" / "ad_title", etc...

You may try to use other names for your CSS class names "ad_item" and "ad_title"

Comment: That was it - thanks very much. I changed the class names and, for now, AdBlock isn't deleting the content. And if this resurfaces in the future, we'll know what to look for.